# How can I be sure that an application is running on same cpu/core that its TCP send flow is?

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, tcp

Let's suppose the following (very simplified egress tcp queuing) flow:

```
 -->[app (nginx)]
 -->[send_buffer(tcp_wmem)]
 -->(qdisc txqueuelen)
 -->[ring buffer(tx_rx)]
 -->(dma)
 -->[nic]
```

For the **tx ring buffer** I can use the driver script to ensure that the affinity and its multiple queues are split by cpu/core.

For the **egress qdisc** I can use the `fq_codel` and for **an application (like nginx)** I do have some ways too (ie: cpu_worker_affinity).

But how I can make sure that an application running on a **CPU/core X** is in the same CPU/core that its network flow (send_buffer) is running?

To sum up, does an application always run (when pined) in the same CPU/core as its tcp send buffer is? (if yes, how does the linux does this?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is [XPS: Transmit Packet Steering](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt). Well documented upstream, this should answer your questions.